# Selenium Runnable JAR error message notification

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I created runnable JAR file for selenium and i am executing it without any issue.

I run the JAR file using command prompt and if there are errors, it will stop execution and throw error in command prompt.

I am wondering how can we catch that error and notify respective person? If i run in eclipse, i can see it in test-output but here i am executing tests using runnable jar file, in this case i will not have test output folder.

How can i get the error results? Is it better to write code for Email with error message or is there a way to create HTML page with error?

Any thoughts are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: could you please provide example of what you've done so far to get better idea about the question here.

Comment: I created Main.java, in which i am opening a webpage and checking title of the webpage. If title of the webpage matches the one i mentioned in java class then the test is successful else it fails.

Comment: still low quality on the question. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It depends very much of how you have implemented your tests. Having a long script in your `main` it quite different from having separated test classes. Thats why you must insert those details in your question. Please read: [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)